# Kosaraju's Algorithm Implementation Problem

Tags: c++, algorithm

```
  #include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

multiset<unsigned long long> connectedComp;
unsigned long long int counter = 0;
unsigned long long int numComponents = 0;

class Graph{
public:
    unsigned long long int size;
    list<unsigned long long> *adjList;
    bool *visited;
    stack<unsigned long long int> s;
    Graph(unsigned long long int);
    void addEdge(unsigned long long int,unsigned long long int);
    void reverse();
    void DFS1(unsigned long long int);
    unsigned long long int DFS2(unsigned long long int);
    void Kosaraju(void);
    void initialize(void);
};

Graph::Graph(unsigned long long int s){
    size = s;
    adjList = new list<unsigned long long>[size];
    visited = new bool[size];
}

void Graph::addEdge(unsigned long long int src,unsigned long long int dest){
    adjList[src].push_back(dest);
}

void Graph::DFS1(unsigned long long int src) {
    initialize();
    stack<int> stack;
    stack.push(src);
    stack.push(src);

    while(!stack.empty()){
        src = stack.top();
        stack.pop();
        if(!visited[src]){
            visited[src] = true;
        }
        else if(visited[src]) s.push(src);

        for(auto it = adjList[src].begin();it!= adjList[src].end();it++){
            if(!visited[*it]){ stack.push(*it); stack.push(*it);}
        }
    }
} 


void Graph::initialize(void){
    for(unsigned long long int i = 0;i<size;i++) visited[i] = false;
}

unsigned long long int Graph::DFS2(unsigned long long int src){
    counter = 0;
    stack<int> stack; 
    stack.push(src); 

    while (!stack.empty()) { 
        counter++;
        src = stack.top(); 
        stack.pop(); 
        if (!visited[src]) 
            visited[src] = true; 

        for (auto i = adjList[src].begin(); i != adjList[src].end(); ++i)
            if (!visited[*i]) 
                stack.push(*i);

    } 
    return counter;
} 

void Graph::reverse(){
    list<unsigned long long> *tempAdj = new list<unsigned long long>[size];
    list<unsigned long long>::iterator it;
    for(unsigned long long int i = 0;i<size;i++){
        it = adjList[i].begin();
        for(it;it!= adjList[i].end();it++){
            tempAdj[*it].push_back(i);
        }
    }
    adjList = tempAdj;  
}

void Graph::Kosaraju(void){
    for(unsigned long long int i = 0;i<size;i++){
        if(!visited[i]) DFS1(i);
    }
    reverse();
    initialize();
    while (!s.empty()){
        unsigned long long int v = s.top(); s.pop();
        if (!visited[v])
        {
            connectedComp.insert(DFS2(v));
            visited[v] = true;
            numComponents++;
        }
    }

}


int main(void){
    Graph g(11);
    g.addEdge(0,2);
    g.addEdge(1,0);
    g.addEdge(2,1);
    g.addEdge(2,3);
    g.addEdge(3,4);
    g.addEdge(4,5);
    g.addEdge(5,3);
    g.addEdge(6,5);
    g.addEdge(6,7);
    g.addEdge(7,8);
    g.addEdge(8,9);
    g.addEdge(9,6);
    g.addEdge(9,10);
    g.Kosaraju();
    for(auto it = connectedComp.rbegin();it != connectedComp.rend();it++){
        cout<<*it<<endl;
    }
}
```

I made a implemetation of Kosaraju's Algorithm for strongly connected components however my implementation computes wrong number of connected components one of them is in the given code. I wonder what is wrong in terms of logic. For instance my code works with such an order of nodes:
    Graph g(5); 
    g.addEdge(1, 0); 
    g.addEdge(0, 2); 
    g.addEdge(2, 1); 
    g.addEdge(0, 3); 
    g.addEdge(3, 4);

Comment: Please do not dual-tag C++ code with the C tag.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you wrote the code, there is no excuse for not being able to debug your own code.  You had a plan in mind when you wrote the code, and hopefully you wrote the plan down.  Single-step through your program  and see where the program diverges from your plan.  Once you see where this occurs, you either make corrections to your program, or determine that the plan was wrong and thus need to reimplement parts of the program.  That's how all programmers should treat code that they themselves wrote.

Comment: Also, this is a good time to learn to use the debugger that comes with the compiler that you're using.

Comment: Actually code works on some cases but not others that's why I could not debug and needed help

Comment: Edit it with comments and I might consider looking into it.

Comment: In `DFS1`, you're supposed to insert vertices in `s` by the increasing value of departure times. A vertex is ready to be marked departed when all of it's neighbors have been marked visited. This would be a easy if DFS is performed via recursion. If done using a stack it becomes a bit complicated. Also, in the above code, `else if(visited[src]) s.push(src);` is incorrect as that is not when a vertex is to be marked departed.